# Finding record that query errored on

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am getting an error on an update query due to a unique constraint.  I understand why I am getting the error, but is there a way to discover which record that caused the error to occur.

example:

```
update user set account_uid = '1234abcd-12ab-12ab-12ab-123456abcdef' where user_uid in (select user_uid from users_temp);    
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "user_uk"
DETAIL:  Key (account_uid, style, value)=(1234abcd-12ab-12ab-12ab-123456abcdef, Login, bob) already exists.
```

I know why I got the error, I would like to know which user caused it.

Thanks

Comment: Isn't that information clearly displayed in the `DETAIL`? Use that information to do a `SELECT`. (I'm not the downvoter, BTW. Just trying to clarify the question and make sure you didn't miss something.)

Comment: If you are going to down vote my post, please have the guts to say why.

Comment: I've already said **I'm not the downvoter**.

Comment: No, the information is not in the detail.  It details the foreign key values of the constraints, but it does not tell me which user caused the error?

Comment: @Ken then that message was not for you

Comment: I don't get this; Either you already have a user with the same account_uid and that means any user you try to update will throw the error, or you have multiple rows in users_temp and updating all of them to the same account_uid will cause the error? Is account_uid unique?

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery gives you the list of user_id values being changed. Take a look at the users you are trying to update and see if you can see a problem:

```
select u.account_uid, u.style, u.value, u.user_id
from   users u
join   users_temp t
    on t.user_id = u.userid
order by u.style, u.value;
```

I'm guessing, you realize, but there just might be a row with an account_id = '1234abcd-12ab-12ab-12ab-123456abcdef', style = 'Login' and value = 'bob' and a row with the same style and value but a different account_id. It's that second row that's giving you the problem.